# How to remove all animation of BottomNavigationView without Helper?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

How to remove all animation of BottomNavigationView without any Helper or proGuard and in easy way with google material dependency `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. We all know by default `BottomNavigationView` has multiple effects like horizontal translation and larger text if menu item selected.

[image: Default]

2. We can remove the translation adding

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    ...
    app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"/>
```

[image: Translation Removed]

3. We can show label and remove the translation together without `app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"` this way

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    ...
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"/>
```

[image: Labeled]

4. If we're not satisfied with number 3, we can still use the same text size as inactive menu by adding `dimens` in `dimens.xml`. By doing this, we pretty much has animation-free of BottomNavigationView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size"
        tools:override="true">12sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

[image]

**BONUS PROBLEM**

But, there is still another problem. What if the menu text is a long text? What if it was made of 2 words?

If that is your question, you will see the long text trimmed when the menu is selected. (Please look at the third menu)

[image: Long Text Problem]

And this is the solution I got after experimenting with `BottomNavigationView`

```
void selectFragment(MenuItem item) {
    item.setChecked(true);

    int itemID = item.getItemId();
    if (itemID == R.id.menu_a) {
        pushFragment(MenuAFragment.newInstance("MENU A"));
    }
    else if (itemID == R.id.menu_b) {
        pushFragment(MenuAFragment.newInstance("MENU B"));
    }
    else if (itemID == R.id.menu_c) {
        pushFragment(MenuAFragment.newInstance("MENU C"));
    }
    else if (itemID == R.id.menu_d) {
        pushFragment(MenuAFragment.newInstance("MENU D"));
    }
    else {
        pushFragment(MenuAFragment.newInstance("MENU E"));
    }

    /**** START FROM HERE ****/

    TextView largeTextView = bottomNavigationView.findViewById(itemID)
            .findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.largeLabel);
    TextView smallTextView = bottomNavigationView.findViewById(itemID)
            .findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.smallLabel);

    smallTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    largeTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Basically, we only have to hide the `largeTextView` and show the `smallTextView`
[image: Long Text Problem Solved]

Want to know more? Just look at this repo [DisableShiftMode](http://github.com/j-elmer123/DisableShiftMode)

Comment: You are amazing! Thanks!

Comment: This is an incredible answer!

Comment: This is a brilliant set of solutions. Covers all the cases. Thanks.

Comment: This is awesome.

Comment: It doesn't work on Android 13.